# preventDefault ontouchmove does not work on Safari on iOS 12

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit

I am trying to prevent scroll on iOS using javascript. I found on a few threads that doing like so should work :

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

However, the behaviour is quite random as it does not always work. At first it does nothing, and then after a while for some reasons (not doing anything particular javascript wise, just scrolling) scroll gets effectively prevented.

Is it a bug from webkit on iOS ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you try this one? `var scrollable = true;

var listener = function(e) {
    if (! scrollable) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', listener, { passive:false });`